# Python Jinja2 call to macro results in (undesirable) newline

Tags: python, macros, jinja2

My JINJA2 template is like below.

```
{% macro print_if_john(name) -%}
{% if name == 'John' -%}
  Hi John
{%- endif %}
{%- endmacro %}
Hello World!
{{print_if_john('Foo')}}
{{print_if_john('Foo2')}}
{{print_if_john('John')}}
```

The resulting output is

```
Hello•World!


Hi•John
```

I don't want the 2 newlines between 'Hello World!' and 'Hi John'. It looks like when a call to macro results in no output from macro, JINJA is inserting a newline anyways.. Is there any way to avoid this? I've put minus in the call to macro itself but that didn't help.

Note that I tested this template and resulting code at http://jinja2test.tk/

Answer (score 5):

The newlines come from the `{{print_if_john(...)}}` lines themselves, *not* the macro.

If you were to join those up or use `-` within those blocks, the newlines disappear:

```
>>> from jinja2 import Template
>>> t = Template('''\
... {% macro print_if_john(name) -%}
... {% if name == 'John' -%}
...   Hi John
... {% endif %}
... {%- endmacro -%}
... Hello World!
... {{print_if_john('Foo')-}}
... {{print_if_john('Foo2')-}}
... {{print_if_john('John')-}}
... ''')
>>> t.render()
u'Hello World!\nHi John\n'
>>> print t.render()
Hello World!
Hi John
```

Note that you can still use newlines and other whitespace within the `{{...}}` blocks.

I removed the initial `-` from the `{% endif %}` block because when you remove the newlines from the `{{..}}` blocks, you want to *add one back in* when you actually do print the `Hi John` line. That way multiple `print_if_john('John')` calls will still get their line separators.

The full template, freed from the demo session:

```
{% macro print_if_john(name) -%}
{% if name == 'John' -%}
  Hi John
{% endif %}
{%- endmacro -%}
Hello World!
{{print_if_john('Foo')-}}
{{print_if_john('Foo2')-}}
{{print_if_john('John')-}}
```