# Python Jinja2 macro whitespace issues

Tags: python, macros, whitespace, jinja2

This is kind of extension to my other question [Python Jinja2 call to macro results in (undesirable) newline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39626767/python-jinja2-call-to-macro-results-in-undesirable-newline).

My python program is

```
import jinja2
template_env = jinja2.Environment(trim_blocks=True, lstrip_blocks=True, autoescape=False, undefined=jinja2.StrictUndefined)
template_str = '''
{% macro print_car_review(car) %}
    {% if car.get('review')  %}
  {{'Review: %s' % car['review']}}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
hi there
car {{car['name']}} reviews:
{{print_car_review(car)}}
  2 spaces before me
End of car details
'''
ctx_car_with_reviews = {'car':{'name':'foo', 'desc': 'foo bar', 'review':'good'}}
ctx_car_without_reviews = {'car':{'name':'foo', 'desc': 'foo bar'}}
print 'Output for car with reviews:'
print template_env.from_string(template_str).render(ctx_car_with_reviews)
print 'Output for car without reviews:'
print template_env.from_string(template_str).render(ctx_car_without_reviews)
```

Actual output:

```
Output for car with reviews:

hi there
car foo reviews:
  Review: good

  2 spaces before me
End of car details
Output for car without reviews:

hi there
car foo reviews:

  2 spaces before me
End of car details
```

Expected output:

```
Output for car with reviews:
hi there
car foo reviews:
  Review: good
  2 spaces before me
End of car details
Output for car without reviews:
hi there
car foo reviews:
  2 spaces before me
End of car details
```

What is undesirable (per car) is an extra newline at the beginning and an extra line before the line '2 spaces before me'

Thanks Rags

Comment: Do you want to remove white spaces or want to keep white spaces?

Comment: @SumanKalyan I've modified my question to clearly state the expected outcome. Hope that clarifies it now

Comment: @RagsRachamadugu, edited my answer to respond to your modified question.

Answer (score 1):

Complete edit of answer.  I see what you're going for now, and I have a working solution (I added in one `if` statement to your template).  Here is what I used, with all other lines of your code unchanged:

```
template_str = '''{% macro print_car_review(car) %}
    {% if car.get('review')  %}
  {{'Review: %s' % car['review']}}
    {% endif %}
{% endmacro %}
hi there
car {{car['name']}} reviews:
{% if 'review' in car %}
{{print_car_review(car)-}}
{% endif %}
  2 spaces before me
End of car details
'''
```

The spacing is exactly how I'm running it on my end, giving exactly the desired output you put in your question.  I confess that I am myself confused by one point, which is that I had to move the first line, `{% macro print_car_review(car) %}`, up onto the same line as `template_str = '''`.  Based on my understanding of the docs, setting `trim_blocks=True` should make that unnecessary, but I must be understanding it wrong.

Hopefully that gets you what you needed.

Comment: See my edited question and let me know if something is still unclear.

Comment: Edited my answer to match with your edited question.

Comment: This works but this is a workaround. My whole point of creating macro was to avoid the caller having to do this if. I have to call this macro 10s of times in my case and each caller is now 2-extra lines. And in reality the condition in my macro is more complicated than this example. Doesn't this look like a bug in JINJA? The use of minus shouldn't be required given trim_blocks=true plus empty new lines shouldn't occur..

Comment: I see.  You might be right.  You can try submitting it over at the [jinja github](https://github.com/pallets/jinja).  Sorry I couldn't provide a better solution for you.

Comment: Thank you for the github, I was struggling to find a place to submit the issue. Filed https://github.com/pallets/jinja/issues/612